# Create a table where the last column of a row is transferred to the first row of the next column

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I am creating a mileage tracker in laravel where I have to calculate miles travelled from the previous odometer value e.g

```
Initial   fuel(LTRs) current    km_travelled
0012005     5.        0012080      75

0012080.    10.       0012160.     80
```

The initial value is inputed by the user the first time, then km travelled = current - initial, this current value will be the inital value for the next entry.

here's a screenshot of my table:

[image: table]

odometer stop of this row should be odometer start of the next one.

I tried this example [php mysql calculating successive rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055228/php-mysql-calculating-successive-rows)

But I haven't gotten it right.

Please help me.

I would love a Laravel way , or a mySQL statement to perform this kind of calculation.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you include the output you want?

Comment: from the example i posted, I want the value under "current" in the first row , transferred to the "initial" column of the next row.

Comment: Can you add your MySQL version (specifically, if you are using MySQL 8 or not)? Also your actual table/data, e.g. which values you have (especially which of the values of "initial", "current" and "km_travelled" are part of your data, and which are calculated)

Comment: I mean the **Actual** output you want like a table not the description.

Comment: Do you mean actual code for the table? I have edited my question to explain better